# Redirecting to PHP page with post data format

Tags: php, jquery, post

I have seen many of the posts in stackoverflow but i'm unable to find my answers so thats why i'm posting here.
Scenario is this:
My Page is having many `div` containers and each div is having EDIT Button and when a user clicks EDIT of any DIV i want the user to be redirected to another page with ID of that `DIV`,
I want to do this whole this using `POST` method.
File edit.php

```
<button class="edit_btn" onclick="edit_ID('$btn_id')">
<script type="text/javascript">


      function edit_ID(array){
        $.ajax({    type:"POST",
                    url:'redirecter.php',
                    data:{editorID:array.split("_")[1]},
                    success:function(data){
                        //window.location.href="editapplication.php";
                    }

                });
      }

</script>
```

File redirector.php

```
<form action='editapplication.php' method='post' name='frm'>
<?php
foreach ($_POST as $a => $b) {
echo "<input type='hidden' name='".htmlentities($a)."' value='".htmlentities($b)."'>";
}
?>
</form>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
document.frm.submit();
</script>
```

Comment: I think we're going to need a litle bit more info, as in: what code are you using and what's failing?! Appart from that, I think you should use AJAX to make all that magic.

Comment: Have a hidden form...one input type hidden and set it to the value of div's id and submit...

Comment: @web-nomad -i tried hidden form and used $.ajax({....}); but when i click to that nothing is happening.

Comment: Why a POST method?  Just putting a clickable link in the `div` with a query string parameter seems a lot easier.  As for what you tried... You'll have to *show* us what you tried in order for us to help.  Saying "I tried and nothing is happening" isn't really a useful description of the problem.

Comment: what function are you using to redirect the user to the other page?

Comment: Well, you are saying that you should be redirected and use POST data... I don't see how AJAX will help you there. As you want to use POST data, this sounds more like a job for cURL to me.

Answer (score 1):

you need to hook the click event of the button, and perform your actions there:

```
$(function() {
    $('#buttonID').bind('click', function(event){
      var id = $(this).parent().id;
      $.ajax({....});
    });
});
```

Comment: I am having fifty or more `DIV` with different ID how can i do this.

Comment: add a class name to those divs "special-class", then: `$('.special-class').bind('click', ...);`